# New command for indexable word in math mode

Tags: macros

What I would like to do is define a new command `\kodim` which I can index in math mode. With the following solution

```
\newcommand{\kodim}{kodim \,}
```

the result is unsatisfactory, because from

```
\kodim_V U
```

I get the space between the word `kodim` and the index `V`, instead of between `kodim_V` and the argument `U`.

How do I have to define the command instead to get the same result as from `\dim_V U`?

I also notice that my new word is not displayed in the same way in math mode as the built-in macro \dim. It is displayed in italic instead. How can I get the same result as with the built-in macro?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator\kodim{kodim}` (amsmath package) will make `\kodim` act like `\log` and just add the space when needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do load the `amsmath` package and issue the instruction

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\kodim}{kodim}
```

in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\DeclareMathOperator" macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\kodim}{kodim}
\begin{document}
$\kodim_V U \quad \dim_V U$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!